# C# WPF Check if text inside textbox is a valid date

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to do a form with some validation but I'm having problems with the `DateTime`

This is my `Person.cs`

```
private string dateBirth;

public string DateBirth
    {
        get { return dateBirth; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == true)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Date is empty");
            }
            else if (value.GetType() != typeof(DateTime))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid date");
            }
            else
            {
                dateBirth = value;
            }
        }
```

This is my `MainWindow.xaml`

```
private void btnSet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person p = new Person();

        try
        {
            p.DateBirth = txtDate.Text;  //this is the textbox I want to check
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
      }
```

If I insert in my `textbox` a date e.g. 01/01/1990, it's always an 'Invalid date', as the second `ArgumentException`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You property is a string type property

```
public string DateBirth
```

The value you got in the setter will always be a string also

```
else if (value.GetType() != typeof(DateTime))
```

Use DateTime.TryParse to convert the string back to Date first

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a string... you have to parse it into a DateTime and check if it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

This is reasonable, because the type of `txtDate.Text` is string. You have to parse first the user's input. Basically, I wouldn't have use a try catch block. I would have tried the following:

```
if(!DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out p.DateBirth))
{
    // The parse failed.
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid date");
}
```

If you use this method, please not this

> Because the DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime) method tries to parse
>   the string representation of a date and time using the formatting
>   **rules of the current culture**, trying to parse a particular string
>   across different cultures **can either fail or return different results**.
>   If a specific date and time format will be parsed across different
>   locales, use the DateTime.TryParse(String, IFormatProvider,
>   DateTimeStyles, DateTime) method or one of the overloads of the
>   TryParseExact method and provide a format specifier.

For further information about this, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime.TryParseExact(..) function does allow you to parse a date using a specific date format (for example, "mm/dd/yyyy"). However, if you want to be flexible on the number of digits in the year, then a regex might be a better choice.

```
if  (!DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, out value))
{
     return false;
}
```